# Get branch name from nodeid in mercurial

Tags: deployment, version-control, mercurial

How can I source the branch name from node ID in Mercurial?
I have tried `hg id nodeid` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But `hd id nodeid` *does* work, provided you spell the node identifier with the `-r` or `--rev` option:

```
$ hg id -r 2
db6f6e1d8715 (sidebr) tip
```

Note that if the branch name is `default` it is suppressed, as usual.

To get *just* the branch name, and avoid suppressing the name `default`, add the `-b` option:

```
$ hg id -b -r 1
default
```

Note that you can get more than one piece of information:

```
$ hg id -i -b -n -r 1
d05b1df8b8f6 1 default
```

(The order is always hash, rev, branch when using these options, regardless of the order of the `-i` / `--id`, `-n` / `--num`, and `-b` / `--branch` options.  Adding `-t` / `--tags` and/or `-B` / `--bookmarks` adds the tags and the bookmarks in that order, again regardless of *option* order.)

Comment: so say my nodeid is 'eff37df408da'. How can i get the branch name?

Comment: @tichra: `hg id -b -r eff37df408da`. If a node ID is given as an integer, that's taken as a sequential revision number; if it's given as a hash ID, it's taken as a hash ID.